# Display data from firestore throws an error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from firestore database and using `*ngFor` directive to display the data in Ionic 4. When I check the console, it shows an error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'todoList' of undefined`. Need help.

**todo.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   const todoList= [];
   var userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
   var getid = userid.uid;
   console.log(getid);

   this.afs.firestore.collection('todos')
   .where('userID', '==', getid)
   .get()
   .then(function(querySnapshot){
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        this.todoList.push({
          id: doc.id,
          Title: doc.data().title,
          Description: doc.data().desc,
        })
     });
   }).catch(function(error){
     console.log(error);
   })
 }
```

At this point, I'm not sure what I did wrong.

**todo.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList">

    <div class="user">
      <span> {{ todo.Title }} </span>

      <p>{{ todo.Description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The 'todo.html` page is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 'losing' the `this` context of the class by using the `function` keyword. You are better of always using the arrow notation `() => {}`

```
// ...
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  // ...
  this.todoList.push({
    id: doc.id,
    Title: doc.data().title,
    Description: doc.data().desc,
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, you are right. I wasn't aware that using `regular function` and `arrow function` gives different result. I always thought both `function` works in similar manner. I need further research on that part. Thank you.